# Possible in Jenkins to add sleep time between build actions?

Tags: jboss, jenkins, hudson

I am starting a JBoss server in Jenkins as a build action. The next action runs a set of tests. I need to add sleeptime between the two actions. Does anyone know how to do this easily?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add `sleep` command (on Unix) in the test build action before test execution.

Comment: As much as this works, it hangs an executor on Jenkins.

Comment: This solution is definitely not platform independent and should be avoided at least when using Jenkins Pipelines.

Answer (score 20):

It is possible to use `sleep` step in your Jenkins Pipeline. The step is included in [Pipeline: Basic Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-basic-steps).

Example:

```
steps {
  sleep time: 250, unit: 'MILLISECONDS'
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#sleep-sleep

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I think this answer must be accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

If you mean to know how to sleep between those build steps you can use `sleep` with `Execute shell` type.

```
sleep 30s
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a built-in feature in Jenkins to put a sleep but it is not easy to find it because they call it differently.

On the following screenshot

[image: screenshot]

You can see there is a `Quiet period` setting in the advanced project options that is "executed" before the current job (project).

If you have 3 jobs you can as well set this setting for jobs 2 and 3 which will make:

```
job1 -> (sleep -> job2) -> (sleep -> job3)
```

Comment: You saved the day mate !! ... thanks, this is a good solution !!

Comment: Good to see it can help, this is the best official way for those who does not use pipelines (and have access to the UI). Otherwise I think Yuri's answer is the best one for pipelines.

Answer (score 5):

I just added a Powershell step to run script with `Start-Sleep -sec 240`

Answer (score 4):

all previous answers are correct, here is more detailed info for linux envirnment.

1. Search you existing Job Configuration for "**Add build step**"
2. Select Execute Shell and then add **sleep some_number**.

[image]
[image]