# Is there limit to how long a Jenkins job can sleep for?

Tags: jenkins

I am dealing with a build pipeline that has some very long wait times in between builds due to outside dependencies. I've found that you can indeed tell a build to sleep before it executes its build steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378185/possible-in-jenkins-to-add-sleep-time-between-build-actions). However, I was wondering if there is a limit to how long the sleep can last for. In some cases I'd like builds to wait for 24 hours between builds in the pipeline, inputting 24hrs as 86400 seconds is a little unsettling, but I suppose it's not that unreasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit implicitly within Jenkins. It will bee limited by your infrastructure reliability and the like.

If you are using jenkins pipeline, ensure that the wait's do not occur whilst consuming an executor (inside a node block).

It may be better, (again if using pipeline) to use a timeout() block rather than a arbitrary sleep, so it resumes as soon as ready.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit